# Issue get Lines Array of String in Label

Tags: ios, objective-c, label

I have a String: "The idea of making a toothpaste and a mouthwashg".

I use bellow code to get last string on label .
Result Strings last line: "and a mouthwashg."
But last line on label display:"toothpaste and a mouthwashg"
How to get exactly string lastline on label?
Here is my code:

```
-(NSArray *)getLinesArrayOfStringInLabel:(UILabel *)label 
{ 
    NSString *text = [label text]; 
    UIFont *font = [label font]; 
    CGRect rect = [label bounds]; 
    CTFontRef myFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)([font fontName]), [font pointSize], NULL); 
    NSMutableAttributedString *attStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text]; 
    [attStr addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge id)myFont range:NSMakeRange(0, attStr.length)]; 
    CTFramesetterRef frameSetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)attStr); 
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable(); 
    CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(0,0,rect.size.width,100000)); 
    CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(frameSetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, NULL); 
    NSArray *lines = (__bridge NSArray *)CTFrameGetLines(frame); 
    NSMutableArray *linesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
    for (id line in lines) 
    { 
        CTLineRef lineRef = (__bridge CTLineRef )line; 
        CFRange lineRange = CTLineGetStringRange(lineRef); 
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(lineRange.location, lineRange.length); 
        NSString *lineString = [text substringWithRange:range]; 
        [linesArray addObject:lineString]; 
    } 
    return (NSArray *)linesArray;
}
```

Comment: Actually what do you want to do? Your question does not clarify it.

Comment: @Rohan Thanks, I edited it .

Comment: What string exactly you want?

Comment: @VirajPadsala It's string display on Label "toothpaste and a mouthwashg"

Answer (score 5):

You can use NSRange to get your string below code helps you:-

```
NSString *strSource=@"The idea of making a toothpaste and a mouthwashg";
NSRange r1 = [strSource rangeOfString:@"toothpaste"];
NSRange r2 = [strSource rangeOfString:@"mouthwashg"];
NSRange rSub = NSMakeRange(r1.location , r2.location + r2.length - r1.location );
NSLog(@"your string:%@",[strSource substringWithRange:rSub]);
```

Comment: oh Thanks, but I want do it with any string on my Label

Comment: you want last 5 words of any string?

Comment: I want with another string on Label, I can get string last line that label display !

Comment: how can you detect that's my last line? you suppose to add separator to evaluate.

Comment: @VirajPadsala is right. You need to add separator to differentiate as last line.

Comment: can you see: [http://imgur.com/a/lV6ev]  . I wan to get last line on Label with anyString input .

Comment: you mean "visit our gallery!"  ?

Comment: sorry @VirajPadsala. I mean http://i.imgur.com/ax0jp0v.png and http://i.imgur.com/yio2wv4.png?1

Comment: you have array get lastObject of array for last line